# calling performSegueWithIdentifier doesn't work

Tags: swift

i have this function in a class, that posts NSNotification, once the user has been identified and the match is prepared to begin. then i have an observer in the mainViewController that triggers this segue:

```
func startMP(){

            performSegueWithIdentifier("MPVC", sender: nil)
}
```

but it doesn't work. what am i doing wrong? 
pd. the authenticationViewController is dismissed once the match is prepared to start.

Comment: Can you explain further about if there any warning message? Also what is the `viewController` stack  so we could understand better and help you.

Comment: no there aren't any warnings. i've added print("message") in the startMP() to see if it works, and the message is printed in the console. then i've added a button that trigger the segue and it works fine. so i think the problem is the way i handle the segue in the startMP() function.